# RavenDB sort by enum

Tags: c#, ravendb

Is it possible to Sort or OrderBy an Enum when making a query to RavenDB? Maybe by giving an IComparable?

I've tried, but it seems like it orders as if the Enum was a string, and it doesn't work for me to store the Enums as integers.

Here's a simple example:

```
public class Car
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfDoors { get; set; }   
    public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }   
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }   
}

public enum Classification 
{
    Compact, 
    Hatch,
    Convertible,
    Muscle
}
```

I would like to order by Classification in this order: Muscle, Compact, Hatch, Convertible. And I would like to avoid having to rearrange the enum and storing the enum as an integer.

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
//My query
var cars = session.Query<Car>()
                    .OrderBy(c => c.Classification , new ClassificationComparer())
                    .Skip(offset)
                    .Take(size);


public class ClassificationComparer: IComparer<Classification>
{
    public int Compare(Classification x, Classification y)
    {
        return Order(x).CompareTo(Order(y));
    }

    private int Order(Classification classification)
    {

        switch (classification)
        {
            case Classification.Compact:
                return 0;
            case Classification.Hatch:
                return 1;
            case Classification.Convertible:
                return 2;
            case Classification.Muscle:
                return 3;
            default:
                return int.MaxValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use the solution proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12235904/390819) that shows how you can persist enums in RavenDB using their underlying `int` values.

However, if you want to keep the `Classification` property as a string and order query results by the `int` value, one possible solution is this:

Create an index that maps the existing Cars and ads the corresponding `ClassificationId`:

```
public class SortableCarIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Car, SortableCar>
{
    public SortableCarIndex()
    {
        Map = cars =>
                from car in cars
                select
                    new SortableCar
                        {
                            Car = car,
                            ClassificationId =
                                Array.IndexOf(new[]{
                                    "Compact",
                                    "Hatch",
                                    "Convertible",
                                    "Muscle"
                                }, car.Classification)
                        };
    }
}

public class SortableCar
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }
    public int ClassificationId { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure the index is present in the database, using the folloing line of code after creating the `DocumentStore`:

```
IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(typeof(SortableCarIndex).Assembly, documentStore);
```

After the index is created, you can query it like this:

```
    var carsOrderedByClassification =
        session.Query<SortableCar, SortableCarIndex>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.ClassificationId)
                .AsProjection<Car>()
                .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. I've come to the conclusion that sorting can only be done on simple types, so you're example is defenitly usable